# Website Viewport is Still Zoom-able and Pinch-able on Safari Browser on Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, safari, viewport

Using Bootstrap 4 skeleton, I have tried Bootstrap built in `viewport` meta tag which is

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

and also used one custom meta from web research like

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, shrink-to-fit=no, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
```

to prevent changing the display of website on Pinch and Zoom in, but in both ceases the website is still `Pinch-able` and  `Zoom-able` in Safari browser in mobile. Tested on Android the web site is not zoom-able but it is on Safari. What am I missing?

Comment: We've ran into the same issue, have you managed to find a solution?

Comment: No! couldn't find any thing and no help from here

Answer (score 0):

Update your view port with following will work. it work for me.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Comment: same thing is happening. still IOS is zoom able